# jqueryui datepicker does not reset other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

When the datepicker element is selected, and the calendar pops up, I also want to set a different select element back to the top option, and also clear a textbox....this is what I am trying and doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#timeremoved").val("");
    $("#timeinplace").val("");
    $("#removed").datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the html code ?

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: <select class="w-select" id="timeremoved" name="timeremoved" data-name="timeremoved" required onChange="calcTime();">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="NIGHT">NIGHT</option>
    <option value="UNK">UNK</option>
    </select>
    <input class="w-input" id="timeinplace" type="text" placeholder="Time in Place" name="timeinplace" data-name="timeinplace" required>